# PHP sort array by two field values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've an array like this

```
Array (
 [0] => Array( "destination" => "Sydney",
               "airlines" => "airline_1",
               "one_way_fare" => 100,
               "return_fare => 300
       ),
 [2] => Array( "destination" => "Sydney",
               "airlines" => "airline_2",
               "one_way_fare" => 150,
               "return_fare => 350
       ),
 [3] => Array( "destination" => "Sydney",
               "airlines" => "airline_3",
               "one_way_fare" => 180,
               "return_fare => 380
       )
)
```

How can i sort the value by return_fare asc , one_way_fare asc ?

I tried [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) but i ended up getting mixed up data..

asort only works for one dimensional array, i need to sort by two values or more, how can i achieve this like in SQL, order by field1 asc,field2 asc ?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

[`array_multisort()`](http://www.php.net/array_multisort) is the correct function, you must have messed up somehow:

```
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $return_fare[$key]  = $row['return_fare'];
    $one_way_fare[$key] = $row['one_way_fare'];
}

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
array_multisort($data, $return_fare, SORT_ASC, $one_way_fare, SORT_ASC);
```

If you take a look at the comments at PHP's manual page for `array_multisort()`, you can find a very helpful `array_orderby()` function which allows you to shorten the above to just this:

```
$sorted = array_orderby($data, 'return_fare', SORT_ASC, 'one_way_fare', SORT_ASC);
```

To avoid the looping use `array_column()` (as of PHP 5.5.0):

```
array_multisort(array_column($data, 'return_fare'),  SORT_ASC,
                array_column($data, 'one_way_fare'), SORT_ASC,
                $data);
```

Comment: thanks..! i think i did it exactly the same u advised. can't find the array_orderby() function though on manual page comments

Comment: @flyclassic, the first comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#100534

Comment: Many Thanks. The array_orderby worked for me. however i had to copy the function for the PHP website.. :)

Comment: reduced my original multiline solution to one line - perfect - thanks

Answer (score 50):

In addition to `array_multisort()`, which requires you to build column-arrays first, there is also [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/usort) which doesn't require such a thing.

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) { 
    $rdiff = $a['return_fare'] - $b['return_fare'];
    if ($rdiff) return $rdiff; 
    return $a['one_way_fare'] - $b['one_way_fare']; 
}); // anonymous function requires PHP 5.3 - use "normal" function earlier
```

Comment: Or more shortly, `return $a['return_fare'] - $b['return_fare'] ?: a['one_way_fare'] - $b['one_way_fare'];` Everything feels more natural than `array_multisort()`

Comment: i stumbled upon this one, i think it should be said that `array_multisort` seems to be significantly faster than `usort` - you can find an example here  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4aeeb7f0639347c1d426ec263a676fd667d43a2f

Comment: Could very well be the case now (back in 2011 there was no arrray_column and so you had to build the arrays yourself which slowed things down considerably).

Comment: A `foreach` loop that generates two arrays is very likely to outperform two separate `array_column()` calls ...if you are worried about micro-optimization.  The benefit of two `array_column()` calls is code brevity and the avoidance of making two variable declarations.

Answer (score 17):

Another example using the spaceship operator.

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) { 
    return $a['return_fare'] <=> $b['return_fare'] ?: $a['one_way_fare'] <=> $b['one_way_fare'];
});
```

Comment: This can be done with a single spaceship operator comparison.

Comment: And yet you don't tell us how @mickmackusa?

Comment: My answer on the duplicate page demonstrates how to do this. @codemonkey

Comment: Here are some more if you like: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2943403+spaceship+operator&mixed=0  For the record, if you are making function calls in the comparisons, then I recommend using multiple spaceships, but if there are no function calls, then it is better to use one spaceship.  My old answers might not toe this line.

Comment: Ah ha.  I'd considered concatenation but knew that wasn't safe - arrays hadn't occured to me, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Or you can use `uasort` as follows

```
uasort($arr, function($a,$b){
    $c = $a['return_fare'] - $b['return_fare'];
    $c .= $a['one_way_fare'] - $b['one_way_fare'];
    return $c;
});
```

[<kbd>**Fiddle**</kbd>](https://eval.in/407793)

Comment: This is not working when sorting with decimal values

Comment: This has been an awesome tip: I was trying to do a double sort (group job IDs then order product IDs within the groups) and this did the trick perfectly (I was looking for a MySQL multi column sort solution, I had tried array_multisort and it was breaking other ordered sections in the groups - this is the only solution that has allowed me to get the desired order in a way I could read and understand, a very important thing when it comes to refactoring further down the line)

Comment: I would never use the concatenated string formed from two difference values.  Even in the cases where it works, there are cleaner techniques available.

Answer (score 9):

I'll answer this in a way that can be *generalized*, no matter how many items you wish to sort on!

Sorting on `return_fare` then `one_way_fare`:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
   if ($a['return_fare'] != $b['return_fare']) {
      return $a['return_fare'] <=> $b['return_fare'];
   }

   return $a['one_way_fare'] <=> $b['one_way_fare'];
});
```

Sorting on `return_fare`, then `one_way_fare`, then `destination`:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
   if ($a['return_fare'] != $b['return_fare']) {
      return $a['return_fare'] <=> $b['return_fare'];
   }

   if ($a['one_way_fare'] != $b['one_way_fare']) {
      return $a['one_way_fare'] <=> $b['one_way_fare'];
   }

   return strnatcasecmp($a['destination'], $b['destination']);
});
```

Sorting on just `return_fare`:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['return_fare'] <=> $b['return_fare'];
});
```

**Note:** you don't have to use an anonymous function with `usort`!

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
   return $a['return_fare'] <=> $b['return_fare'];
}

usort($data, 'cmp');


// Use a function inside a class:
class MyClass {
   public static function compare($a, $b) {
      return $a['return_fare'] <=> $b['return_fare'];
   }
}

usort($data, ['MyClass', 'compare']);
```

You can also chain these using the Elvis Operator (`?:`):

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
      return $a['return_fare'] <=> $b['return_fare'] ?:
             $a['one_way_fare'] <=> $b['one_way_fare'] ?:
             strnatcasecmp($a['destination'], $b['destination']);
});
```

This last example used the Spaceship Operator (`<=>`) and the Elvis Operator (`?:`). Isn't programming great?

Answer (score -2):

Ohh, i managed to solve my own question again....

```
function array_multi_sort($array, $on1,$on2, $order=SORT_ASC) 
{

    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        $one_way_fares[$key] = $value[$on2];
        $return_fares[$key] = $value[$on1];
    }

    array_multisort($return_fares,$order,$one_way_fares,$order,$array);
}
```

The thing is i missed out the last parameter $array on `array_multisort($return_fares,$order,$one_way_fares,$order,$array);`

earlier!