# php sorting array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```
$user_data = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$user_data[$row['id_user']]['id_user'] = $row['id_user'];
$user_data[$row['id_user']]['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
$user_data[$row['id_user']]['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
$user_data[$row['id_user']]['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];
}
```

I'd like to sort it using php (not sql or Jquery) by firstname for example.

Comment: Read up on the PHP Function [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this after while loop and try :

```
$sort = array();
foreach($user_data as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['firstname'][$k] = $v['firstname'];
}

array_multisort($sort['firstname'], SORT_DESC, $user_data);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($user_data);
```

Not tested, If you are getting any issue, please comment here.

Comment: I'm getting this: Warning: array_multisort(): Argument #1 is expected to be an array or a sort flag

Comment: Ohh.. I am sorry it is `$sort['firstname']` not `$sort['point']`.. i edited it now please check it

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.sort.php).

You should use the `SORT_STRING` flags to sort by firstname.

Answer (score 0):

What you will probably want to use is php's uasort function. It allows you to specify your own comparison function that will be used in the sorting process.

PHP documentation: [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

Answer (score 0):

Sort it by firstname in your database query:

```
...
ORDER BY firstname
```

After all, it is database that retrieves the data. No point doing the work again of dealing with data when you could have done that in the first step.

Comment: _not sql or Jquery_ => He doesn't want to use SQL.

Comment: Not sure whether delete my answer or the OP omitted the option of sql because of being not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

The manual for `array_multisort` has an [**example**](http://de.php.net/array-multisort#example-4796) exactly for this use case:

> ```
> $data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 2);
> $data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 1);
> $data[] = array('volume' => 85, 'edition' => 6);
> $data[] = array('volume' => 98, 'edition' => 2);
> $data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 6);
> $data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 7);
>
> // Obtain a list of columns
> foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
>     $volume[$key]  = $row['volume'];
>     $edition[$key] = $row['edition'];
> }
>
> // Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
> // Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
> array_multisort($volume, SORT_DESC, $edition, SORT_ASC, $data);
> ```

Comment: The same as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4582659/1384214).

Comment: It seems like it should work, however it does not. Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Could you take a look at my code at OP and tell me how exactly should I write the sort code?

Comment: Never mind, I got it.