# PHP: multi dimension array with multiple sort

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with 4 values each

```
$array[0] = array('amount' => '98.60', 'typeA' => '98.52', 'typeB' => '58.52', 'typeC' => '90.2');
$array[1] = array('amount' => '55.80', 'typeA' => '25.36', 'typeB' => '36.54', 'typeC' => '36.99');
$array[2] = array('amount' => '42.68', 'typeA' => '64.26', 'typeB' => '65.87', 'typeC' => '99.24');
$array[3] = array('amount' => '812.3', 'typeA' => '36.27', 'typeB' => '23.25', 'typeC' => '94.35');
```

I need to arrange the array according to the highest value of each key with the sequence of:

1. typeA
2. typeB
3. typeC

so in the end I will get to see which is the amount that comes up top.

Hope some help can be given here, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$data = array(array('amount' => '98.60', 'typeA' => '98.52', 'typeB' => '58.52', 'typeC' => '90.2'), array('amount' => '55.80', 'typeA' => '25.36', 'typeB' => '36.54', 'typeC' => '36.99'), array('amount' => '42.68', 'typeA' => '64.26', 'typeB' => '65.87', 'typeC' => '99.24'), array('amount' => '812.3', 'typeA' => '36.27', 'typeB' => '23.25', 'typeC' => '94.35'));

// Obtain a list of columns

foreach ($data as $key => $row) {

```
$volume[$key]  = $row['typeA'];
$edition[$key] = $row['typeB'];
$edition1[$key] = $row['typeC'];
```

}

array_multisort($volume, SORT_DESC, $edition, SORT_DESC, $edition1, SORT_DESC, $data);

echo ''; print_r($data);

Answer (score 1):

> **array_multisort()** can be used to sort several arrays at once, or a multi-dimensional array by one or more dimensions.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

```
<?php
    $data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 2);
    $data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 1);
    $data[] = array('volume' => 85, 'edition' => 6);
    $data[] = array('volume' => 98, 'edition' => 2);
    $data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 6);
    $data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 7);

    // Pass the array, followed by the column names and sort flags
    $sorted = array_orderby($data, 'volume', SORT_DESC, 'edition', SORT_ASC);
?>
```

Here is another great example of its use:

[PHP sort array by two field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582649/php-sort-array-by-two-field-values)