# array_push or array_unshift multiple rows to top of same array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I have an array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 1
        [Order] => 1
        [ContentGroupId] => 10
        [ContentGroupIsNew] => 0
 )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 2
        [Order] => 2
        [ContentGroupId] => 11
        [ContentGroupIsNew] => 0
 )
[2] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 3
        [Order] => 3
        [ContentGroupId] => 12
        [ContentGroupIsNew] => 1
 )
[3] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 4
        [Order] => 4
        [ContentGroupId] => 13
        [ContentGroupIsNew] => 1
 )
[4] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 5
        [Order] => 5
        [ContentGroupId] => 14
        [ContentGroupIsNew] => 0
 )
```

The default order is by `[Order]` I want to re-sort this array so that it orders by `[ContentGroupIsNew] = 1` at the top (if any exist, in this sample 2 do exist), but keep the existing order of the remainder of elements.

If I use a `usort` function, I can get the `[ContentGroupIsNew] = 1` but then the remainder of elements seems to get randomly ordered and not keep true to the original `[Order]` value.

So the final result should look like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 3
        [Order] => 3
        [ContentGroupId] => 12
        [ContentGroupIsNew] => 1
 )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 4
        [Order] => 4
        [ContentGroupId] => 13
        [ContentGroupIsNew] => 1
 )
[2] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 1
        [Order] => 1
        [ContentGroupId] => 10
        [ContentGroupIsNew] => 0
 )
[3] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 2
        [Order] => 2
        [ContentGroupId] => 11
        [ContentGroupIsNew] => 0
 )
[4] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 5
        [Order] => 5
        [ContentGroupId] => 14
        [ContentGroupIsNew] => 0
 )
```

PHP code:

```
function sort_array($b, $a) {
  return $a['ContentGroupIsNew'] - $b['ContentGroupIsNew'];
}

usort($array, 'sort_array');
```

Comment: What does your code look like? Modifying the condition in your `usort()` function should be easy.

Comment: @jeroen added PHP to end of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $return_fare[$key]  = $row['ContentGroupIsNew'];
    $one_way_fare[$key] = $row['Id'];
}


array_multisort($return_fare, SORT_DESC, $one_way_fare, SORT_ASC, $data);
print_r($data);
```

found this solution here :  [PHP sort array by two field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582649/php-sort-array-by-two-field-values)

Comment: This got me close, but the examples from that other solution [PHP sort array by two field values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582649/php-sort-array-by-two-field-values) got me there. Thx.

Comment: Glad to help, how current sorting code looks like ? just interested what did you change.

Comment: `usort($app_iaps, function($a, $b) { 
        $rdiff = $b['ContentGroupIsNew'] - $a['ContentGroupIsNew'];
        if ($rdiff) return $rdiff; 
        return $a['Order'] - $b['Order']; 
    });`

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
   function myCmp($a, $b)
    {
      return strcmp($b["ContentGroupIsNew"], $a["ContentGroupIsNew"]);
    }

    uasort($array, "myCmp")

echo "<pre>"; print_r($array);
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work, but the next solution got me there. thx for help.